# Saving Custom Object (within another custom object) to User Defaults in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I have created two types of custom objects:

1. The first object, called Contact, has 4 fields which store Strings.
2. The second object, called ContactList, has 1 field which stores a list of my first object `[Contact]`.

In my View Controller, I have an instance of a ContactList that I would like to save into User Defaults. Looking through other questions, I have added the following methods into the Contact class (as well as making it inherit from NSObject, and NSCoding)

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.firstName = (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "first") as? String)!
    self.lastName = (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "last") as? String)!
    self.phoneNumber = (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "phone") as? String)!
    self.email = (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "email") as? String)!
}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder){
    aCoder.encode(self.firstName, forKey: "first")
    aCoder.encode(self.lastName, forKey: "last")
    aCoder.encode(self.phoneNumber, forKey: "phone")
    aCoder.encode(self.email, forKey: "email")
}
```

And then in my ContactList class, I have added two functions:

```
func saveData(){
    let data  = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: list)
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(data, forKey:"contacts" )
}

func retrieveData(){
    if let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "contacts") as? NSData
    {
        list = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data as Data) as! [Contact]
    }
}
```

In my View Controller, I'm calling `saveData()` on my current instance of ContactList. In my `ViewDidLoad` method, I have an assignment statement to my variable which holds the instance of this by creating a new instance and then calling `retrieveData()` on it.

However, when I run my program and add elements to the list in ContactList's list field, exit out, and then come back into the app, the elements that I added is not there (I have a table that updates and displays the contents of the list in the ContactList).

Am I supposed to have ContactList inherit something, or am I just implementing these methods wrong? This is the first time that I'm using UserDefaults, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't do this.  Use CoreData.  Yes, there is a learning curve, but it is better than spending time making NSUserDefaults do something it isn't suited for

Comment: Oh okay. I'll check out CoreData then.